# Quasi-Monte Carlo with Conditional Distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, monte-carlo

I want to estimate $E(f(X))$ using quasi-Monte Carlo where $X = (X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is a random vector and
$$
X_i\sim f(\cdot; \theta), \quad \text{independent},
$$
where $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ is some known parameter and $f(\cdot; \theta)$ is a pdf for each $\theta$.  Let's say I want to use the Halton sequence.  Usually, I would generate an $n$-dimensional Halton sequence $(H_1,\ldots,H_N)$ where $N$ is the number of Monte Carlo runs and each $H_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  Then (after transforming to $f(\cdot;\theta)$ random variables) my estimate is
$$
E(f(X)) \approx \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^n f(H_i)
$$
Now I want to specify the distributions of the $X_i$ as
\begin{align*}
X_i \mid \theta & \sim f(\cdot;\theta), \quad \text{independent}, \\
\theta \sim g,
\end{align*}
where $g$ is a pdf.

My question is, what is the dimension of the Halton vector I should use in this case?  Or, should I generate two Halton sequences, one of dimension 1 and the other of dimension $n$?